# How to show Applovin/Max Banner Ad with layout?

Tags: android, banner, banner-ads, applovin

I am new to `Applovin/Max`. In their [documentation](https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/getting-started/banners) `position` and `size` of `Banner` ad set by programmatically.
Thats why `BannerAd` override my app's `content`.

Banner layout in `xml`

```
<com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView
        android:id="@+id/maxBannerAdLayout"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/banner_height" />
```

In documentation banner show progrmatically

```
adView = new MaxAdView( "YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID", this );
adView.setListener( this );

// Stretch to the width of the screen for banners to be fully functional
int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

// Get the adaptive banner height.
int heightDp = MaxAdFormat.BANNER.getAdaptiveSize( this ).getHeight();
int heightPx = AppLovinSdkUtils.dpToPx( this, heightDp );

adView.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( width, heightPx ) );
adView.setExtraParameter( "adaptive_banner", "true" );

// Set background or background color for banners to be fully functional
adView.setBackgroundColor( ... );

ViewGroup rootView = findViewById( android.R.id.content );
rootView.addView( adView );

// Load the ad
adView.loadAd();
```

I have no idea,
How can I connect code with `banner layout`?

Comment: Use the XML OR the java code, don't use them both, here's an example of XML usage : https://github.com/AppLovin/AppLovin-MAX-SDK-Android/blob/master/AppLovin%20MAX%20Demo%20App%20-%20Java/app/src/main/java/com/applovin/enterprise/apps/demoapp/ads/applovin/banner/BannerLayoutEditorActivity.java

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI this reference not helpful. This not mention BannerId in his code. ALso this is outdated according to sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: When you create `Ad Id` in Applovin/Max that time you provide
> `package` Name. Only Test ads on that same package name app otherwise not showing any real ad.

Here I explain Full process of showing `Max/Applovin` `Banner ad` (with fb/Meta).

add `dependency` in `build.gradle` of applovin and fb.(if you use other network then add their `dependency` with applovin. (always check latest dependency version- [here](https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/mediation-adapters))

```
//applovin and fb dependencies
implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.6.1'
implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:facebook-adapter:6.12.0.2'
implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:facebook-adapter:6.12.0.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
```

add this code me `manifests.xml` bottom. Here in `value` put your `sdk key` you can find it in `Applovin >Account > Keys > sdk Key`

```
      ....
    <meta-data
        android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
        android:value="@string/sdkKey" />
</application>
```

Place `Banner ad` code om `xml` where you want

```
<com.applovin.mediation.ads.MaxAdView
        xmlns:maxads="http://schemas.applovin.com/android/1.0"
        maxads:adUnitId="Add_here_YOUR_AD_ID"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/maxBannerADDDD"
        />
```

Java code

```
    private MaxAdView adView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //find Id of xml Banner 
    adView = (MaxAdView) findViewById(R.id.bannerADDDD);
    initializeAdNetwork();
}

private void initializeAdNetwork() {
    
    AppLovinSdk.getInstance( this ).setMediationProvider( "max" );
    AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(getApplicationContext(), new AppLovinSdk.SdkInitializationListener() {
        public void onSdkInitialized(AppLovinSdkConfiguration appLovinSdkConfiguration) {
            loadInterstitial();

            //load banner Ad
            loadBannerAd();
        }
    });



}

private void loadBannerAd(){
    adView.loadAd();
    adView.startAutoRefresh();
}
```

Also add `Internet permission` in app.

If you use `facebook/Meta ads` then must use `network_security_config`.
make this `xml` inside `res > xml`  *(if you not find xml then Right click on res > new > create Directory named **`xml`**) inside this xml directory create this below xml file.*

**network_security_config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

also declare this file in `menifest.xml`

```
    ...
<application 
  
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
    ....
```

Thanks.

**Happy Coding:)**

Answer (score 1):

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bannerad"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Java code:

```
private MaxAdView adView;

private void LoadBannerAd() {
    adView = new MaxAdView( getResources().getString(R.string.bannerad), this );
    adView.setListener(new MaxAdViewAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdExpanded(MaxAd ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdCollapsed(MaxAd ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(MaxAd ad) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdDisplayed(MaxAd ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdHidden(MaxAd ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(MaxAd ad) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoadFailed(String adUnitId, MaxError error) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdDisplayFailed(MaxAd ad, MaxError error) {

        }
    });

    int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int heightPx = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize( R.dimen.banner_height );
    adView.setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( width, heightPx, Gravity.BOTTOM) );
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.bannerad);
    ll.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd();
}
```

Call the LoadBannerAd() inside your onCreate().

The problem is, you are using both the ways:

1: Using XML and java code
2: and programatically also.

Try the above code.

I know it's late to answer this question but may be this can help someone in future.